# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum not saving

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to save an image that is currently in my image view to the Camera Roll. The image I'm trying to save shows up perfectly in the image view, via `[mainImage setImage:outputImage];` However, when I try to press the button that saves the image:

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([mainImage image], self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

}

-(void)image:(UIImage*)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void*)contextInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

The camera roll is empty. I'm using iOS7 simulator. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The Assertion doesn't say anything either.

~Carpetfizz

Comment: Take advantage of the rest of the parameters to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`. The selector that is called has an error parameter you can look at to see why it is failing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I get `(null)` as the error.

Comment: Is `image` nil or not in the callback method?

Comment: Has the app ever prompted you for permission to access your photos? You can check using <code>[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]</code> to see if the app has permission.

Comment: Yes, it asked for my permission, and it's enabled in the Privacy tab.

Comment: It's absolutely late, but for anyone having the same issue, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46396718/7113238

Answer (score 14):

This took me a while to figure out...

I am not exactly sure why, but if the `UIImage` you are trying to save is backed by a `CIImage` (i.e. `image.cgImage == nil`), `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` will oddly successfully complete with a `nil` error object in the completion handler, but nothing will show up in photos.

If this is the case, you can convert the `UIImage`'s `CIImage` to a `CGImage` (**Swift 4.1**):

```
// this could also be made into an extension
func cgImage(from ciImage: CIImage) -> CGImage? {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)
}
```

Then convert back to a `UIImage` (these two steps can be combined):

```
guard let ciImage = image.ciImage else { return }
guard let cgImage = cgImage(from: ciImage) else { return } // the above function

let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage) // ready to be saved!
```

I hope this solution can save someone the aggravation that this problem caused me .

Comment: Thanks! This helped me fix my issue. `guard let cgImage = cgImage(from: cgImage)` should be `guard let cgImage = cgImage(from: ciImage)`

Comment: Thanks, this definitely saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and searched for the answer. Though I am not sure it's exact the same cause, I hope this can give you a little insight.

My suggestion is to check [mainImage image]. It might return nil even it shows up perfectly in image view.

In my case, I should use `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` instead of `info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]`, which returns nil and that's why it was never saved.